# Accessing github repository using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to access github repositories using github api in node.`

```
var https = require("https");
var userName='sacdh22';
var options = {
    host :"api.github.com",
    path: "/users/" +userName+ "/repos",
    method : 'GET',
    headers: {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.0)'}
  }

var request = https.request(options, function(response){
    var body = '';
    response.on('data',function(chunk){
        body+=chunk;
    });
    response.on('end',function(){
        var json = JSON.parse(body);
        var repos =[];
        console.log(json);
        //json.forEach(function(repo){
        //    repos.push({
        //        name : repo.name,
        //        description : repo.description
        //    });
        //});
        console.log('the repos are  '+ JSON.stringify(repos));
    });

});
request.on('error', function(e) {
    console.error('and the error is '+e);
});
request.end();
```

When i console.log(body) I get the following output.

```
    {"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
{ message: 'Not Found',
  documentation_url: 'https://developer.github.com/v3' }
```

Can any one tell me what is going wrong here, my guess is that the path is not set properly, so how can I set it?

Comment: Why are you lying about your user-agent?

Comment: thats what I am not able to understand what is that useragent .

Comment: It's Internet Explorer 7, which clearly isn't the software you are using to make the request. (It's unlikely to be related to your problem, but it is very strange)

Comment: @Quentin this is what the documentation contains.   headers: {
        "user-agent": "My-Cool-GitHub-App" // GitHub is happy with a unique user agent
    },

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sacdh22` is not a username on Github. When you try to access a list of their repositories, Github gives you a Not Found error. Change the username to a real one and you will get [very different results](https://api.github.com/users/jquery/repos).